# How to include SR related work log long description when using maximo oslc rest api?

Tags: json, rest, api, maximo, websphere

I am doing an HTTP GET request to /maximo/oslc/os/mxsr and using the oslc.select query string parameter to choose:

```
 *,doclinks{*},worklog{*},rel.commlog{*},rel.woactivity{*,rel.woactivity{*}}
```

This lets me get related data, including related worklogs, but the worklog does not include the 'description_longdescription' field.

The only way I seem to be able to get that field is if I do a separate HTTP GET to query a worklog id directly through /maxrest/rest/mbo/worklog . Then it provides the description_longdescription field.

I understand this field is stored separately through the linked longdescription table, but I was hoping to get the data through the "next gen" oslc api with one http get request.

I've tried putting in 'worklog{*,description_longdescription}', as I read somewhere that longdescription is a "non-persistent" field and must be explicitly named for inclusion, but it had no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that for the /maximo/oslc/os/mxsr object in the API, I needed to reference the related MODIFYWORKLOG object through the rel.modifyworklog syntax in the oslc.select query string:

```
 oslc.select=*,doclinks{*},rel.modifyworklog{*,description_longdescription},rel.commlog{*},rel.woactivity{*,rel.woactivity{*}}
```

I also had to explicitly name the non-persistent field description_longdescription for it to be included.

Ref. for the "rel." syntax: https://developer.ibm.com/static/site-id/155/maximodev/restguide/Maximo_Nextgen_REST_API.html#_querying_maximo_asset_management_by_using_the_rest_api